# How to collapse navbar menu on click ONLY, not open, having trouble figuring this one out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so I'm trying to create a navbar that collapses the hamburger menu when a link is closed. The problem is the method I'm using also opens the hamburger menu when I click a link. This is okay with all the regular links in the navbar. But I do not want this to happen with the navbar-brand. I need it to only collapse the menu when it's opened. However, even when the menu is closed the navbar-brand on click will open it.

here is the code, I tried all sorts of javascript but I think I need help with my specific situation.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#brand" data-target="#navbar"><img style="height:31px; width:170px;" src="images/img.svg"></a>

        <!-- Start Collapse Button -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- End Collapse Button -->
    </div>

    <!-- Start Links -->
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <!-- Left Links -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#it" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">IT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#cloud" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#navbar">CLOUD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hipaa" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#navbar">HIPAA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#security" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#navbar">SECURITY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contactus" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#navbar">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutus" data-toggle="collapse"data-target="#navbar">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- End Links -->
</div>
```

Comment: your jQuery code please! Can you show where are doing, "The problem is the method I'm using also opens the hamburger menu when I click a link".?

Comment: I placed your code in a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVpmrp) and I cant seem to replicate the issue you are having. I can only assume you have javascript code else where on the page that is causing this behaviour.

Comment: In your pen, if you noticed. Clicking on the navbar-brand doesnt close the menu. How can I make that happen, and not the other way around

Comment: Normally @SudhansuChoudhary I would use data-toggle="collapse" for the navbar brand, but it also opens the menu, which is something I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook up to the click event of the hamburger and reset the css classes on the menu

```js
$('.navbar-brand').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', false);
  $('.navbar-toggle').addClass('collapsed');
  $('.navbar-collapse').attr('aria-expanded', false);
  $('.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse');
  $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#brand" data-target="#navbar">
        <img style="height:31px; width:170px;" src="http://lorempixel.com/170/31" />
      </a>

      <!-- Start Collapse Button -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <!-- End Collapse Button -->
    </div>
    <!-- Start Links -->
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <!-- Left Links -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#it" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">IT</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#cloud" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">CLOUD</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#hipaa" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">HIPAA</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#security" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">SECURITY</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contactus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">CONTACT US</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#aboutus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">ABOUT</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Links -->
  </div>
```